# What's the best way to get a HashTable in PHP?

Tags: php, hashtable

Isn't there any built in class in PHP that has HashTable in PHP? If not, what's the best way to use one. Implementing from scratch?

Comment: What functionality are you looking for specifically that an associative array does not provide?

Comment: The reason you can't find one is that the basic Associative Array is a hash table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PHP's associative array as a hash table.

[From PHP Manual on Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

Comment: Correction. PHP's associaltive arrays are not simply 'as' a hash table. They specifically ARE a hash table. :)